# How to expose Docker and/or Kubernetes ports on DigitalOcean

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

First off I want to say I am in no way inexperienced, I am a professional, and I have been Googling this issue for a week; I've followed tutorials and also largely found threads on this site that tell people they're asking for free labor and the answer is on Google. The answer is not on Google, so please bear with me. I have been working on my "homework," as people like to say here, and I am missing something significant.

My use case: I want to run code-server and JupyterLab as browser-accessible services on a DigitalOcean droplet OR Kubernetes cluster. I would like to do this in a way that allows as much of my budget for hosting as possible to be used for processing software (I write Python machine learning/natural language code). My ideal setup is that I have a subdomain, with SSL (LetsEncrypt is fine), for code-server and another for JupyterLab. Ideally they can access the same storage, but that's a secondary concern for the moment. I'd be okay with not having a domain and just passing traffic through OpenVPN to an IP and ports, but code-server just won't run full featured without SSL.

The actual problem: on nearly every attempt to implement this, I have found that I cannot access ports. On a good attempt, I manage to get one service (often something like Python http.server) where going to my domain or IP/port gets me anything other than "connection refused" instantly. I've checked firewall settings (I don't use DigitalOcean's and I have consistently opened the ports that my native services and/or Docker containers are listening on/being forwarded to). Best I pulled off was using Kubernetes and [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-the-code-server-cloud-ide-platform-on-digitalocean-kubernetes) following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm): I got code-server and two example sites running in separate subdomains (pointed using a node balancer, and yes, I have a fully registered domain on DO's name servers).

There was a problem however: I couldn't get LetsEncrypt to issue a certificate on Kubernetes and I didn't know how to get it into the container for code-server.

That gets me to my next problem, which is relevant bc I'm not sure this is entirely a Kubernetes problem: I have not successfully exposed a port in any Linux distro in the past four years. I used to administer multiple sites on a single Linode, from 2012-16 or so, and it was no problem, although probably quite insecure, but I'm talking not even being able to expose ports on IP addresses now. Something in how cloud providers handle things has changed. I know AWS, GCloud etc. isolate their VMs on private networks but that's not what DO, Linode, or Vultr do, and yet I can't so much as expose a port successfully - even if I follow port exposing tutorials for the distro in question. I've literally used Rancher to launch a Docker container on a port, managed by the OS, and verified that port is exposed, and it just doesn't work. With Kubernetes SOMETIMES the load balancer helps here. I also was able to get a full server up in FreeBSD but too much of what I need to run depends on Docker and Node which sadly haven't been ported well to that system.

I want to note that I've also Googled StackOverflow and found other people with similar issues, but their questions were all closed there and they were told to Google; Googling turns up DO tutorials and the closed
StackOverflow threads. I should note I've also tried to do this on Google Cloud and Linode with similar results.

ALSO: I'm aware Docker containers are isolated by default from the OS network and have followed guidelines for deployment to make sure their OS-native ports are forwarded.

tl;dr; I'm having trouble exposing ports, despite following OS procedures, and also I am not sure if my personal development server for just me to use should be a Kubernetes cluster or a single server with Docker deployment, and I don't know how to route ports to subdomains for the two apps I want to expose if I'm not using a Kubernetes load balancer. Please don't close this as somehow "too broad" when it's an incredibly narrow situation, other people have had it, and I've been doing my research for a week.

Comment: well, In my personal experience I did find the answer in google, but I can share it here, DigitalOcean offers the Load Balancer service that is the endpoint where you can expose those ports that you need, on that node you should install the cert for SSL, if you don't want to pay for that, you can setup a ingress node yourself but you need another vps just for that.

Comment: Also, you really need to have all that on containers? sounds overkill for me, for what I understand this is personal use only, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I do use the Load Balancer DO offers. And it's helped, some - once I was able to use it to get several things up on subdomains. The problem was the encryption thing I mention above - I couldn't get LetsEncrypt to issue a certificate for a Kubernetes cluster, and code-server absolutely won't work properly without SSL. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: The cert should go only in the load balancer instance, not in the kubernetes cluster itself, you only need `public` encryption on the side that gets exposed

Comment: Sebastian - in the case of code-server and its main competitor, running in containers is the default. It is for personal use only and if this was the old days I'd gladly just install from package managers or compile it from git, but it literally seems as if it's become nearly impossible to allow web access to services on a VM since I last administered one four years ago (when I successfully ran multiple sites and a forum off of one Linode). I've tried this on one big non-containerized VM and these problems were even harder to deal with.

Comment: Ellie - check this out https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/#ssl-certificates

Comment: @Sebastian, I must be doing something wrong then. I did put a certificate in the load balancer pointing to code-server, and did the redirect of HTTPS traffic to HTTP as specified in that tutorial, but going to code-server dot my domain still provided only HTTP traffic, which in addition to being insecure also disabled several features automatically.

Comment: It looks like in the case of the DO Load balancer you need to upload the cert and call it by id

Comment: You know what? I'll try to do it too, I need to do it in the future so if I understand how to do it I will write my findings here

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, those last two comments will hopefully solve my issue. Not sure how I missed that page you linked but it looks like exactly what I need

Comment: And also, check the next part, "Forced SSL Connections", probably you also need to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: FIxed! I'd mark you comment as an answer, but I don't think we can do that with comments? Thanks!

Comment: Ellie, I can put the link as an answer so it's easy to other people to find hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find where to do it here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/#ssl-certificates